# Convert Ruby hash key/value pairs as values in an array?

Tags: ruby, hash

I want to convert the hash's key/value pairs to only be values. For example, my hash is:

```
{"place"=>1, "gentleman"=>1}
```

I want that has to be like this:

```
[{'word'=>'place','count'=>1},{'word'=>'gentleman','count'=>1}]
```

Comment: however one is "gentleman" and the other one is "gentlemen". In my case, it is different entries.

Comment: When you create a sample input, in your case, the hash, *reduce it* to be minimum necessary needed to demonstrate your problem. Anything beyond that wastes time and space.

Comment: Also, the value for `"place"` is `1`. How does the `count` in the desired output become `2`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try something like

```
my_hash.map { |word, count| {'word' => word, 'count'=> count} }
```